# Is there someone to help me with Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate an id using Jasper Report,
for that I have to concantenate fields and a field (the second one) must carry 2 Zeros before.
I've tried with this but not working.
my code: $F{NUM_ORDRE} + "" + **NUM ($V{COLUMN_COUNT}, '000')** + "" + $F{CODE}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin `TEXT` function.  As in

```
$F{NUM_ORDRE} + "" + TEXT($V{COLUMN_COUNT}, "000") + "" + $F{CODE}
```

You can see a list of builtin functions [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/FunctionsReport.html).  I think the Jaspersoft Studio expression editor also has the list of available functions.